# Android: Facebook always shows You have already authorized application dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.1.2 and testing on Android 4.4.2 - Knowing that I have Facebook application uninstalled from my mobile for test purposes, which means that logging in and authorizing my application is via webview provided by FB SDK.

**I get this message in a dialog everytime I clear the memory "You have already authorized {Application Name}"**

How to avoid this message to appear repeatedly which will ruin user experience?

Knowing that and based on the code below, everytime I clear the mobile memory AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() returns null when application starts, which leads in my code to run the 2 lines below, which I believe is responsible for this message.

```
        List<String> PUBLIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION = Arrays.asList("public_profile");
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PUBLIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION); //Log in to FB
```

**My logging in code flow, and please pitch in if it could be improved:**

```
AccessToken mAccessToken;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken)
        {
            updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
        }
    };
}
```

**// updateWithToken(...) function**

```
private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null)
    {
        mAccessToken = currentAccessToken;
        AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(currentAccessToken);
    }
    else
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                // App code
                mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(mAccessToken);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception)
            {
                Log.d("", "");
            }
        });

        List<String> PUBLIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION = Arrays.asList("public_profile"); // public_profile
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, PUBLIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION); //Log in to FB
    }
}
```

**// onDestroy() function**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
}
```

**// onActivityResult(...) function**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: It shows "You have already authorized {Application Name}" because the logged in user already accepted the permission that is required to approve the login. If you want to see the first screen which shows an 'Accept' button, you must revoke the access from the Facebook Allowed App Panel.

Comment: Thanks, I already know the reason, but how to avoid it, if I comment the most first 2 lines it causes error when making graph request (an access token is required).

Comment: This is expected behavior on both Android / iOS when you don't have the native apps installed. There's no way to get a redirect directly back to the app without pressing Okay on the Webview.

Comment: But it gives me this dialog when I try to access publish permission,which is not granted before.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this message when in onSucesss() I logged in as follows:

**Code**

```
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        String s = object.getString("first_name") + " " + object.getString("last_name");
                        inputName.setText(s);
                        inputEmail.setText(object.getString("email"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
          }
```

But then I changed the last line as follows:

**Code After Edit**

```
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email"); // parameters to get from facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

and that message disappeared.

**EDIT 2**

However, I just found out that after I logout from Facebook, using

```
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

and then I login again, the message came back. But as long as I did not logout programatically and instead I clicked on the Log Out button of Facebook (after I login the message on the button changes to "Log Out"), that message did not show up.

**EDIT 3**

Final solution to the problem is by deleting permission before logging out, as follows (replace the variable FBuserID with the actual userID you got from facebook using loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId():

```
private void logOut(){
    GraphRequest delPermRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + FBuserID + "/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            if (graphResponse != null){
                FacebookRequestError error = graphResponse.getError();
                if (error != null)
                    // error
                else
                    // SUCCESS
            }
        }
    });
    delPermRequest.executeAsync();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```